# Magento 2: Customizing the template files

Tags: magento2, template

When we customize the core template files in Magento 2, how should we name the folder in the custom theme?.

For example, I want to customize the template file in \vendor\magento\module-advanced-search, how would I name the folder in the Custom theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It so easy,
Suppose, you had modified below file:

**vendor/magento/module-advanced-search/view/frontend/`templates/search_data.phtml`**

Then you have to copy **search_data.phtml** to below location of your theme.

`app/design/frontend/{ThemeVendorname}/{Themename}/Magento_AdvancedSearch/templates`

**Format like** path

`app/design/frontend/{ThemeVendorname}/{Themename}/{ModuleName}`+ Path after `vendor/magento/module-advanced-search/view/frontend`